# How to handle System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException error when getting values from JSON by Property Name

Tags: c#, json, linq

I can successfully extract data from the following JSON using the code below:

```
string json = @"{
  "person": {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "cars": [
      {
        "make": "Ford",
        "model": "Focus",
        "year": 2003
      },
      {
        "make": "Toyota",
        "model": "Yaris",
        "year": 2015
      }
    ]
  }
}";

JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);

string name = (string)rss["person"]["name"];
//This will return John

string car1 = (string)rss["person"]["cars"][0]["make"];
//This will return Ford

string car2 = (string)rss["person"]["cars"][1]["make"];
//This will return Toyota
```

If the JSON changes and the car array only contains one item, I get the following error for car2:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Index was out of
>   range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

This is because there is no item in position 1 of the car array. If this happens I would like the car2 string to be set to an empty string.

Is there a way i can check to see if an item exists before trying to extract the value?

I've included psuedocode below to explain what im looking trying to achieve:

```
if exists(rss["person"]["cars"][1]["make"])
then string car2 = (string)rss["person"]["cars"][1]["make"]
else string car2 = ""
```

Thanks in advance

*References - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm*

Comment: `JsonPath` will be really helpful here. First store array of cars in a separate variable and then You can get last or first element from it

Comment: why don't you deserialize the json to class structure. In that case cars will be converted to `IEnumerable` object where you can check the `Count`? Also, deserializing to a type would provide additional capabilities so you don't need to do type casting too by yourself.

Comment: When `cars` has only 1 item will it be just 1 items in `{}` or it will be in an array `[{ }]`? I think that is the root of your problem

Comment: Totaly agree with User1672994, Deserialise to a real object and use LinQ from there. LinQ2Json is more usefull when you want to parse only one part of the object into a real object but still not parse the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need just to check on the count of cars first.

```
JArray cars = (JArray)rss["person"]["cars"];
string car1 = "";
string car2 = "";
if(cars.Count > 0)
{
   car1 = (string)cars[0]["make"];
}

if(cars.Count > 1)
{
   car2 = (string)cars[1]["make"];
}
```

Check [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4PNLLR)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the json string to typed object using `JsonConvert.DeserializedObject` method. As per provided input the Json class would be represent as follows :

```
public class Car
{
    public string make { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public List<Car> cars { get; set; }
}

public class PersonResponse
{
    public Person person { get; set; }
}
```

Using above types, the input Json can be converted as follows :

```
var personResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonResponse>(json);
```

Now, the cars can be accessed as :

```
var car1 = personResponse.Person.cars.First()?.make;
```

and car2 as

```
if (personResponse.Person.cars != null && personResponse.Person.cars > 1)
{
    car2 = personResponse.Person.cars[1].make;
}
```

With above typed classes, you don't need to type casting by yourself.

The `DeserializeObject` definition is referenced at [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm).